# How pca() function works in matlab

Tags: matlab, pca

I'm trying to apply pca() function on 3 dimensional data, But I'm getting empty COEFF matrix

```
x1 = randn(400,1);
y1 = randn(400,1);
z1 = randn(400,1);
plot3(x1,y1,z1,'r.');
[COEFF] = pca([x1;y1;z1]')
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Your input should be an `n x p` matrix, not an `1 x n*p` matrix. 2) Why the screenshot instead of copy/paste?

Comment: @beaker it worked. Can you please answer it, so that I can accept your answer.